# Initializing an Big integer array

Tags: java

My code:

```
BigInteger R;
int Height;
 BigInteger[][] results = new BigInteger[String.valueOf(Height)][R];
```

Getting an error for this please help me out.

Comment: You need to say what the error is! Just edit your question to add the details of the error message you're receiving.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing

```
String.valueOf(Height)
```

???

Height is an int.

This code works :

```
 BigInteger R = new BigInteger("5");
 int Height = 5;
 BigInteger[][] results = new BigInteger[Height][R.intValue()];
```

R is a BigInteger and the [] needs an Integer so we call the inValue method to turn it into an int.

Answer (score 1):

Array sizes in java are `int`s. So assuming `R` is initialized:

```
BigInteger[][] results = new BigInteger[Height][R.intValue()];
```